# How take join on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

In my system there are three layers

```
BDM can add Agent
DSA can add Agent

Agent can add customer
```

In agent there are two columns agent_bdm_id and agent_dsa_id
I will store zero if Agent is added by BDM and vice versa

I need to print customers with agent and bde/ dsa name

```
BDM bdmid, bdmname
DSA dsaid, dsaname

Agent agent_id, agent_name, agent_bdm_id, agent_dsa_id

customer cust_is, cust_name, cust_agent_id
```

Comment: A better way to ask this question would be to provide example input, desired output, actual output and the query you have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.cust_is, a.cust_name,
        b.agent_name,
        COALESCE(c.bdmname, d.dsaname) `BDM/DSA`
FROM    customer a
        INNER JOIN Agent b
            ON a.cust_agent_id = b.agent_id
        LEFT JOIN BDM c
            ON b.agent_bdm_id = c.bdmid
        LEFT JOIN DSA d
            ON b.agent_dsa_id = d.dsaid
```

*I'm a bit confused. Why `0`? isn't it the `ID` who added the `Agent`?*

Comment: I need customer id = 15 or any cust_id

Comment: then add a `WHERE` clause at the end. `WHERE a.cust_is = 15`

Comment: not working select * 
  FROM customer c

        INNER JOIN Agent a
            ON c.customer_agent_id = a.agent_id
        LEFT JOIN BDM b
            ON a.agent_bdm_id = b.bdm_id
        LEFT JOIN DSA d
            ON a.agent_dsa_id = d.dsa_id
where customer.customer_id = 15;

Comment: can you add sample records? You know where i'm confused of? this statement, *I will store zero if Agent is added by BDM and vice versa*, if you will store `0` how will you know that a certain record from `BDM` or `DSA` adds the `AGENT`?

Comment: don't use `customer.customer_id = 15` but the alias instead `c.customer_id = 15`

Comment: yes if agent added by bdm then agent_dsa_id = 0 and if agent added by dsa then agent_bdm_id =0 I have records with id 0 in bdm and dsa

Comment: what happens if you execute this query? `SELECT  a.cust_is, a.cust_name,
        b.agent_name,
        COALESCE(c.bdmname, d.dsaname) BDMDSA_Name
FROM    customer a
        INNER JOIN Agent b
            ON a.cust_agent_id = b.agent_id
        LEFT JOIN BDM c
            ON b.agent_bdm_id = c.bdmid
        LEFT JOIN DSA d
            ON b.agent_dsa_id = d.dsaid
WHERE a.cust_is = 15` ?

Comment: customer also need record from cheque table

Comment: then where's your cheque table?

Comment: cheque has cheque_id and customer table has cust_cheque_id